# Как ускорить стандартный поиск Wordpress, ооочень медленный сейчас?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Расширил стандартный поиск Wordpress вот такими функциями:

````
function cf_search_join( $join ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( is_search() && !is_admin() ) {
        $join .= ' LEFT JOIN ' . $wpdb->postmeta . ' ON ' . $wpdb->posts . '.ID = ' . $wpdb->postmeta . '.post_id ';
    }

    return $join;
}

add_filter( 'posts_join', 'cf_search_join' );

// Modify the search query with posts_where
function cf_search_where( $where ) {
    global $pagenow, $wpdb;

    if ( is_search() && !is_admin() ) {
        $where = preg_replace(
                "/\(\s*" . $wpdb->posts . ".post_title\s+LIKE\s*(\'[^\']+\')\s*\)/",
                "(" . $wpdb->posts . ".post_title LIKE $1) OR (" . $wpdb->postmeta . ".meta_value LIKE $1)", $where );
    }

    return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'cf_search_where' );

//Incude comments in search
function search_comments_join($join) {
    global $wpdb;

    if( is_search() && !is_admin() ) {
        $join .=' LEFT JOIN '.$wpdb->comments.' ON '.$wpdb->posts.'.ID = '.$wpdb->comments.'.comment_post_ID ';
    }

    return $join;
}
add_filter('posts_join', 'search_comments_join');

function search_comments_where($where) {
    global $wpdb;

    if( is_search() && !is_admin() ) {
        $where = preg_replace(
            "/\(\s*".$wpdb->posts.".post_title\s+LIKE\s*(\'[^\']+\')\s*\)/",
            "(".$wpdb->posts.".post_title LIKE $1) OR (".$wpdb->comments.".comment_author LIKE $1) OR (".$wpdb->comments.".comment_content LIKE $1)",
            $where
        );
    }

    return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'search_comments_where');

// Prevent duplicates
function cf_search_distinct( $where ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( is_search() && !is_admin() ) {
        return "DISTINCT";
    }

    return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_distinct', 'cf_search_distinct' );

//Limit posts in search results
function limit_posts_per_search_page() {
    if ( is_search() && !is_admin() )
        set_query_var('posts_per_archive_page', 10);
}
 
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'limit_posts_per_search_page', 9999);```

Однако теперь поиск работает медленно, как оптимизировать?
````

Comment: Запустите ваш запроc внутри EXPLAIN и проверьте индексы

Comment: Ну а что вы хотели - postmeta value, comment author, которые без индексов и ещё сверху DISTINCT, который всегда убивает скорость выполнения

Comment: Можно как-то ускорить работу с помощью Transient API, например?

Comment: @spoilt вы можете кешировать запросы минут на 5 используя объектный кеш (если это не плагин для вп.орг).